# XMPPFramework Facebook Login digest-md5

Tags: facebook, authentication, xmpp

whenever i try to login with the sample app for osx from the xmppframework, the code runs with plain authentication and so it returns invalid username and password.
if i skip the test and give it direct md5 login, it cannot use the md5 because:

```
> <__NSArrayM 0x610000049b70>(
> <mechanism>X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM</mechanism>,
> <mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism> )
```

all i get are these 2 mechanisms. 
also, when connecting to google talk, it works.

ps: i used chat.facebook.com and port 5222. every setting is correct

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facebook xmpp chat api does not support Digest-MD5. It only supports PLAIN and X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM sasl mechanism so in order to login with plain sasl use facebook username and password. If you want to use X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM you will need api key and access token.

Refer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/